# How to return Null instead of nothing in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am writing a postgres query where I ask to return each order for each user. In case of the user hasn't a order I would like to return Null instead of no return.

My current query:

```
Select Order.user_id, 
       User.name, 
       Order.id, 
       Order.value, 
       Order.item
FROM Order
       Left Join User
       On Order.user_id = User.id
```

it returns each user order but in case of user with no order, nothing is returned. How I can return Null  (or any string) instead of no return?
Thank you so much.

Comment: Use `right` instead of `left` if you want all rows from the rightmost table (users)

Comment: Yeah, it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want a `left join`, but you want `user` first:

```
SELECT u.id as user_id, u.name, o.id, o.value, o.item
FROM User u LEFT JOIN
     Order o
     ON o.user_id = u.id;
```

I also introduced table aliases so the query is easier to write and to read.  And . . . change `o.user_id` to `u.id` in the `SELECT` so it has a value when there are no orders.